# Can I make a custom tooltip on a highcharts drilldown?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a custom tooltip for a drill down series on high charts.

I imagine it would look something like this.

```
   tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                if (series is drill down) {
                    return :'tooltip A';
                } else {
                    return :'tooltip B';
                }
            }
        },
```

But I can't find any examples and "series is drilldown" is obviously not code.

Comment: Puzzled by this myself, so here's a basic drilldown demo to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `levelNumber` property in series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/qLcZr/2/

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            if(this.series.levelNumber == 1) { 
                 return 'first level';   
            } else {
                 return  'parents level';
            }
        }
    },
```

OR:

For each series you can set `pointFormat` (formatter per series is not supported), see: http://jsfiddle.net/qLcZr/3/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'parent series'  
        },
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
```

Comment: +1 for `levelNumber`. Sometimes I wish all of these items were documented, however.

Comment: All properties are documented pretty well, in source ;) `levelNumber` property is not part of official API, that means one that it may be changed to another name or even removed.

Comment: Yes, source is "documented". I just mean things like this should be made official as they allow full control of the chart. Like pie charts and the start radians, etc.

Answer (score 1):

@Paweł Fus

there is no `levelNumber` property, and function false in [your script](https://jsfiddle.net/qLcZr/2/)

but there is a `drilldown` property can be use

```
pointFormatter: function() {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty("drilldown")) {
        return "<b>{series.name]:({point.y}) parent</b>";
    } else {
        return "<b>{series.name}:({point.y}) child</b>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both series and drilldown.series contain a tooltip object. This means you can customize each one individually in the correct part of the options object.

Check here:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.tooltip

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.series